# Any English equivalent for the French expression, “endormir quelqu'un avec des propos"?

Tags: translation

In French, one can figuratively use the expression, “endormir quelqu'un," meaning that by using some lengthy/boring/loose explanation, we make the interlocutor less vigilant, thereby 
forgetting about a few things that you know they had in mind but that you want them to forget during the discussion (e.g. X knows that Y is going to complain about Z during a discussion, so X will talk in such a way that Y will forget or get confused and/or forget to mention or insist on Z).

Is there any equivalent English expression?

EDIT: Interestingly, I saw the verb "sleep" being used in a similar fashion in gang slang:

[image]

Comment: It won't necessarily work in all contexts, but when it *does* fit, to [***lull** someone into a false sense of security*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lull+into+a+false+sense+of+security) is a very common idiomatic usage. Perhaps in the specific context OP has in mind, the interlocutor becomes so relaxed and reassured he mistakenly thinks his concerns have been properly addressed, so he fails to explicitly bring them up and demand truly satisfactory answers.

Comment: Using the WordReference translation and your explanation also reminds me of the idiom [_bore someone to death_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/bored-to-death?q=bored+to+death), although this phrase isn't generally associated with the purpose of distracting someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We speak of *burying* either the hearer or the matter to be avoided *in facts/data/statistics/paperwork*.

We also use an opposite image, drawn from dance: *Dazzle 'em with footwork*, meaning to discourse so eloquently and interestingly on another topic that hearers fail to observe that we have evaded the topic they are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

In English, this expression is known as *changing the subject*.

A person can also be *dissuaded* from remembering, but that is way too formal for regular conversation.

A better example would be to *distract* someone.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

**Muddy the waters.**

**Put up a strawman.**

Answer (score 0):

The translation I would use is, "Put someone to sleep." (As a distraction from the real issue.)